# Issue with maven in AWS CodeCommit

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-codecommit

I am having an issue with using AWS CodeCommit. My code compiles on my local using mvn clean install, however it doesn't work on AWS CodeCommit. During the build process it fails with "Error while executing command: mvn clean install. Reason: exit status 1". Below are both my pom.xml and buildspec.yml files. Just wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.smartgwt/smartgwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.5-patch</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
             <version>1.12.96</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install
```

Edit:
Here are the last lines of the console output:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar (72 kB at 370 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.10.5/ant-1.10.5.jar (2.2 MB at 11 MB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.5.1/maven-plugin-annotations-3.5.1.jar (14 kB at 73 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (44 kB at 224 kB/s)
[INFO] Created EpisodePath [/codebuild/output/src412799936/src/target/generated-sources/jaxb/META-INF/JAXB]: true
[INFO] Ignored given or default xjbSources [/codebuild/output/src412799936/src/src/main/xjb], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[INFO] Ignored given or default sources [C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/PJGreen Stuff/spring-boot/src/main/resources/countries.xsd], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[WARNING] No XSD files found. Please check your plugin configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  21.399 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-28T23:06:30Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (xjc) on project spring-boot: : MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Command did not exit successfully mvn clean install exit status 1
[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: mvn clean install. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/10/28 23:06:31 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

Comment: Please add the build log output to your question.

Comment: Added the build log output

Comment: Looks like you have an absolute path in your config: `[INFO] Ignored given or default sources [C:/Users/Maks/Desktop/PJGreen Stuff/spring-boot/src/main/resources/countries.xsd], since it is not an existent file or directory.
`